# Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string js php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I saw questions about this problem on overflow, but i can't find the decision.
This is last variant of my code.
Sorry but I absolutely 0 in php :(

```
<?php 
    $host = "*****";
    $user = "*****";
    $pass = "******";

    $databaseName = "******";
    $tableName = "product";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    $dbs = mysqli_select_db($con, $databaseName);
    $sql = ( "SELECT * FROM $tableName");

    $data = array();
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row(mysqli_query("$con", "$sql")) )
    {
      $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode( $data );
    mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
```

why I receive error

Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in /home/**/public_html/php/api.php on line 15

on this string

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row(mysqli_query("$con", "$sql")) )
```

Comment: You are mixing mysqli and mysql.  You are also doing no error handling at all to make this easier to debug. You get no bonus points for cramming as much stuff as possible into each line of code.  I would highly suggest breaking that line up and providing proper error handling around each step in the query process.

Comment: to add to @MikeBrant, don't put your $con and $sql in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes can be seen in the comment below

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$databaseName );    //add the database name
//$dbs = mysqli_select_db($con, $databaseName);           //you can remove this then
$sql = ( "SELECT * FROM $tableName");
try                                                         //add a try catch to handle error
{
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);                        //add result variable

    if($result)                                             //check if result was successful
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))                //use mysqli_fetch_array instead
        {
            $data[] = $row; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('Unable to get data:'.mysqli_error($con));   //error message
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();              //print out error
}


mysqli_free_result( $result );                          //free the resources after used
mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the query and get a result before looping -

```
$sql = ( "SELECT * FROM $tableName");
$result =  mysqli_query($con, $sql); // remove quotes from variables, only query once

$data = array();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) )....// loop through results
```

There are many more improvements you can make to the code. You're assuming the query will always work, you shouldn't. You're assuming that you'll always connect to the database, you won't. You're mixing database methods, you shouldn't (mysql_ vs. mysqli_)

Answer (score 0):

As the above commentors mention your specific error is coming because of this line:

```
  $row = mysql_fetch_row(mysqli_query("$con", "$sql"))
```

If you look at the specific error it mentions you're trying to convert a MySQLi object into a string.  mysqli_query expects you to pass in a string and a mysqli connection and a query (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).  When you have "$con" passed in, you're trying to convert the $con object (a mysqli class) into a string and this is breaking.

In regards to the rest of the code there are other issues mentioned above and in comments, but this will fix the specific error you have

```
 mysqli_query($con, "$sql")
```

Though you don't need the quotes around $sql either, since it's already a string

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
        $host = "*****";
        $user = "*****";
        $pass = "******";

        $databaseName = "******";
        $tableName = "product";

        $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
        $dbs = mysqli_select_db($con, $databaseName);
        $sql = ( "SELECT * FROM $tableName");

        $data = array();
        $dataquery= mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        while ( $row = $dataquery->fetch_array() )
        {
          $data[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode( $data );
         mysqli_close($con);
       ?>
```